# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'html' of undefined or null reference" In Dynamic Creation of controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[image]

I used JQuery for dynamic creation of controls. And 
I got some error like

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'html' of undefined
>   or null reference

Script As Follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 2;
        $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if (counter > 10) {
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                return false;
            }
            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                 .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Width #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtWidth' + counter + '" value="" >'

                  + '<label>Height #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtHeight' + counter + '" value="" >'

                    + '<label>Length #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtLength' + counter + '" value="" >'

                    + '<label>Weight #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
                  '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                  '" id="txtWeight' + counter + '" value="" >'

                  );
            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }
            counter--;
            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        });

        $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                msg += "\n Width #" + i + " : " + $('#txtWidth' + i).val();
                msg += "\n Height #" + i + " : " + $('#txtHeight' + i).val();
                msg += "\n Length #" + i + " : " + $('#txtLength' + i).val();
                msg += "\n Weight #" + i + " : " + $('#txtWeight' + i).val();
            }
            alert(msg);
        });
    });




<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Width #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='txtWidth1' >
        <label>Height #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='txtHeight1' >

        <label>Length #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='txtLength1' >
        <label>Weight #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='txtWeight1' >
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

These are the codes.Kindly please help me to solve this.,

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/u9hvp/

Answer (score 0):

remove the line breaks in "newTextBoxDiv.after().html()"

Comment: i tested your code, nothings seems to be wrong. no errors. you have a live version to show?